# How can unlimited telegram update

Tags: c#-4.0, telegram-bot

How can I increase telegram bot update or remove it on c#?
Now my telegram bot updating is limited to 100 items.

Thank you...!
Morteza Mousavi

Comment: Welcome to [so]! At this site you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour] and read **[this](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347937/)**.

Answer (score 2):

It's Telegram API limit, you can't get more than 100 items at one time.

But you can wrap a function to [getUpdates](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#getupdates) with `offset`, and return a larger result